# PHP Comparar celdas de un xls con archivos .PDF

Tags: php, excel, pdf

comunidad!
Espero me puedan ayudar, Mediante PHP cargo un .xls y una carpeta la cual contiene varios archivos PDF´s. En el Excel tengo los nombres en distintas celdas como se tienen que renombrar los archivos.

¿Tienen alguna idea como se puede hacer?, Les agradezco.

[image: PHP Comparar .xls y .pdf]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: con programacion se puede hacer.